# Browser extension to prevent page reloads upon pressing "Back"

Tags: browser, google-chrome-extensions, browser-addons, safari, safari-extensions

I've noticed in the last couple years that many websites now do a full page refresh every time you return to the page by pressing the <kbd>Back</kbd> button. This is very annoying, especially on cellular or slower internet connections.

Can a browser extension prevent this page reload being triggered upon pressing <kbd>Back</kbd>?

Note: I'm *not* talking about a reload forced by the browser or OS due to memory pressure. This is a proactive reload that the website itself triggers upon sensing that the page has been made active or gained focus again.

The worst offender is [Reddit](https://old.reddit.com). If you click on a topic to read the comments, then press <kbd>Back</kbd>, there's a 5 second delay as the topic list is reloaded, all the votes are recalculated, all the comments are tallied, etc. I don't want any of that to happen, I just want to quickly go back to the previous topic list I had been viewing.

Test yourself on various websites. Click on a topic/comments, then press <kbd>Back</kbd>.

- https://old.reddit.com (must be logged in)
- https://stackoverflow.com
- https://news.ycombinator.com

Hacker News and Stack Exchange are both pretty fast. No reload. No recalculations. Just shows you the previous topic list.

Reddit is dreadfully slow and forces a full page reload every time you press <kbd>Back</kbd>. Other websites do this as well.

I'm searching for a browser extension for Safari or Chrome that can prevent this entire class of page reload, on all websites. What mechanism are the websites using to trigger a reload/refresh and how can it be intercepted and blocked?

Comment: If you avoid the older legacy version of Reddit does it behave the same way?

Comment: They're all instantaneous to me - but tbh the initial first-time page load isn't something I'd get impatient about, maybe 1s for DNS to find the page, then instantaneous load. The back button removes the apparent wait for DNS, so is entirely instantaneous. Perhaps we have wildly different line speeds, or we have more nodes to traverse, so I can't say anything definitive. …or maybe you already have too many extensions weighing it down?

Comment: @Tetsujin per the answer here, you apparently must be logged in to see the delay on Reddit.

Answer (score 1):

HTTP Response headers for the HTML pages from Reddit look like this,

```
accept-ranges: bytes
cache-control: private, s-maxage=0, max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-store
```

So the web site is asking the browser not to cache the page, via the max-age flag.

However for some elements of the page, like Javascript files, they do request caching (for 7 days, which is 604800 seconds).

```
accept-ranges: bytes
cache-control: max-age=604800
```

So a large part of the content should be cached. Maybe your phone or internet connection is slow?

Comment: Good find. That brings up [this bug report](https://www.reddit.com/r/bugs/comments/j8nccw/the_cachecontrol_response_header_sent_to_loggedin/) that explains how those headers break the back button for logged-in users. Definitely something that an extension may be able to fix.